# second input should appear ONLY AFTER first input field filled in

Tags: jquery, forms, events, input

I'm looking to figure out some way where 'second input should appear ONLY AFTER first input field filled in'.

I tried to research on that on Foogle, jquery site and stackoverflow but couldn't find anything.

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "filled in" ? You could keep the second input field hidden(invisible or display:none), and then make it appear, using a JavaScript function to check if the first field is "filled in".

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#first").keyup(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  if ((id).length > 5) {
    $("#second").fadeIn("slow");
  }
  else
    {
      $("#second").fadeOut("slow");
    }
})
```

```css
#second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="text" id="second">
```

i hop it may help you

Comment: Thank you priya! That exactly help in jsfiddle. Even for unknown reasons that code doesn't work within an app built with jquery and angular both at the same time.